# Limit maximum rows of SQLite and shift the whole table accordingly

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

What I want to do sounds easy to implement until I began to think about all the details... So I have a game with 3 difficulties and I save the scores achieved in each in 1 table. The table has 2 columns, one for the score and one invisible to the user for the difficulty so I can sort the scores accordingly. But currently the game is saving any score achieved with no order or maximum count which is not very convenient. Instead I want to limit it to the 3 highest scores for each difficulty and then when the top score for the *easy*  difficulty is achieved it should add that score to the first row shift the rows and delete the one that used to be 3th before for that difficulty.

Here is how the SQL is storing my scores currently:
[image]
what I want to do is limit the row to 9, currently it will keep adding to infinity and after that to make it store the 3 highest scores for each difficulty so that when they are displayed on the ListView in the app they are in decreasing order

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want to do.

Comment: I uploaded a picture with the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, insert the new score. Then you want to delete the lowest score for that difficulty.

For a specific difficulty *X*, this query lists the rows you want to keep:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE difficulty = X
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

So you want to delete all rows that are not in that list:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE difficulty = X
  AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID
                 FROM MyTable
                 WHERE difficulty = X
                 ORDER BY score DESC
                 LIMIT 3);
```

(This statement works correctly even if there are not yet three scores.)